# Vertical table lines are discontinuous with booktabs

Tags: tables, rules, booktabs

I created a table in LaTeX, but there are some problems with the borders. The borders remain open whereas I want them closed. Also, in the last row, I want the vertical line gone, ie I want just one column in the last row. Can someone please fix it? Here are my code and my table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{table} [h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Parameters  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 2}\\ 
    \midrule

&  Coefficient & 95\% CI
&   Coefficient & 95\% CI \\ 
    \midrule

   $\beta_{concern_2}$  &   $0.190^{\ast}$ & (0.113, 0.268) & 0.171 & (0.100, 0.241)\\
   $\beta_{concern_3}$   &  0.117 &  (0.043, 0.191)  & 0.117 & (0.050, 0.183)\\ 
    $\beta_{concern_4}$ & 0.210  &  (0.139, 0.281)  & 0.190 & (0.127, 0.253)\\ 
     $\beta_{concern_5}$ & 0.204 & (0.135, 0.273)   & 0.111 & ( 0.049, 0.173)\\  
    $\beta_{breath_2}$  &  0.157 & (0.07,8 0.236) & 0.208 & (0.136, 0.280) \\
     $\beta_{breath_3}$ & 0.115 & (0.041, 0.189) & 0.100 & (0.034, 0.166) \\
    $\beta_{breath_4}$ & 0.236 &  (0.160, 0.311) & 0.301 & ( 0.234, 0.368)\\  
    $\beta_{breath_5}$ & 0.092 & (0.020, 0.163) & 0.079 & (0.015, 0.144) \\
   $\beta_{weath_2}$  &   0.164 & ( 0.092, 0.236) & 0.137 & (0.071, 0.203) \\
    $\beta_{weath_3}$  & 0.160 &  (0.089, 0.231) & 0.199 & (0.135, 0.263) \\
   $\beta_{weath_4}$ &  0.141 & (0.067, 0.215) & 0.133 & (0.066, 0.199) \\
    $\beta_{weath_5}$ & 0.176 & (0.103, 0.249) &  0.257 & (0.191, 0.323)\\ 
    $\beta_{sleep_2}$  & 0.111 & (0.036, 0.187) & 0.135 & (0.068 0.203)  \\ 
    $\beta_{sleep_3}$  & 0.110 & (0.036 0.184) & 0.176 &  0.110 0.242 \\   
    $\beta_{sleep_4}$  &  0.131 & (0.056 0.205 & 0.162 & 0.095 0.229 \\  
    $\beta_{sleep_5}$  & 0.011 & (-0.064, 0.086) & 0.034 & (-0.033, 0.101) \\ 
    $\beta_{act_2}$ &  0.135 & (0.060, 0.209) & 0.033 & (-0.033, 0.100) \\
    $\beta_{act_3}  $ &0.195 & (0.121, 0.269) & 0.203 & ( 0.137, 0.268)\\  
    $\beta_{act_4}  $ & 0.214 & ( 0.139, 0.290) & 0.254 & (0.186 0.321) \\ 
    $\beta_{act_5}  $ & 0.224 & (0.154, 0.294) & 0.158 & (0.095, 0.221) \\
\hline
    & *statistically significant at 5\% level \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Regression Coefficients of model 1 and model 2 }
\label{beta}
\end{center}
\end{table}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but shouldn't you add a `|` also in the `\multicolum`s (i.e: `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Model 1} `)?

Comment: The commands provided by `booktabs` work correctly only in absence of vertical rules. Remove them and your table will be better (use also `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`, though).

Comment: As the Indices are words you could do the follwing `$\beta_{\text{concern}_2}$`, to do that just add `\usepackage{amsmath}` to your preamble.

Comment: This is not really a minimum working example. BTW did you read the `booktabs` documentation? It discourages `\hline` and `|`. Perhaps that's why the output looks so bad.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

That's by design: the author of `booktabs` hates vertical rules in tables and I fully agree with him. You could act on spacing parameters, namely

- `\abovetopsep` (0pt by default), used above a `\toprule`
- `\belowbottomsep` (0pt by default), used below a `\bottomrule`
- `\aboverulesep` (0.4ex by default), used above a `\midrule`, `\cmidrule` or `\bottomrule`
- `\belowrulesep` (0.65ex by default), used below a `\midrule`, `\cmidrule` or `\toprule`

They are all rigid length (no `plus` or `minus` specifications are allowed and they wouldn't make sense anyway).

By (locally) setting these parameters to zero, the vertical rules will match, but it would simpler not to use `booktabs` commands at all: the heavier  `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` would be completely out of place.

Don't use vertical rules and the appearance of your table will improve immediately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}}
\newcommand{\nm}[1]{\textnormal{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{LCRCR}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Parameters} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1}    &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 2}    \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}

&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coefficient} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{95\% CI}     &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coefficient} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{95\% CI}     \\
\midrule

\beta_{\nm{concern}_2} & 0.190\makebox[0pt][l]{$^{\ast}$} 
                               & ( 0.113, 0.268) & 0.171 & ( 0.100, 0.241) \\
\beta_{\nm{concern}_3} & 0.117 & ( 0.043, 0.191) & 0.117 & ( 0.050, 0.183) \\
\beta_{\nm{concern}_4} & 0.210 & ( 0.139, 0.281) & 0.190 & ( 0.127, 0.253) \\
\beta_{\nm{concern}_5} & 0.204 & ( 0.135, 0.273) & 0.111 & ( 0.049, 0.173) \\  
\beta_{\nm{breath}_2}  & 0.157 & ( 0.078, 0.236) & 0.208 & ( 0.136, 0.280) \\
\beta_{\nm{breath}_3}  & 0.115 & ( 0.041, 0.189) & 0.100 & ( 0.034, 0.166) \\
\beta_{\nm{breath}_4}  & 0.236 & ( 0.160, 0.311) & 0.301 & ( 0.234, 0.368) \\
\beta_{\nm{breath}_5}  & 0.092 & ( 0.020, 0.163) & 0.079 & ( 0.015, 0.144) \\
\beta_{\nm{weath}_2}   & 0.164 & ( 0.092, 0.236) & 0.137 & ( 0.071, 0.203) \\
\beta_{\nm{weath}_3}   & 0.160 & ( 0.089, 0.231) & 0.199 & ( 0.135, 0.263) \\
\beta_{\nm{weath}_4}   & 0.141 & ( 0.067, 0.215) & 0.133 & ( 0.066, 0.199) \\
\beta_{\nm{weath}_5}   & 0.176 & ( 0.103, 0.249) & 0.257 & ( 0.191, 0.323) \\
\beta_{\nm{sleep}_2}   & 0.111 & ( 0.036, 0.187) & 0.135 & ( 0.068, 0.203) \\ 
\beta_{\nm{sleep}_3}   & 0.110 & ( 0.036, 0.184) & 0.176 & ( 0.110, 0.242) \\   
\beta_{\nm{sleep}_4}   & 0.131 & ( 0.056, 0.205) & 0.162 & ( 0.095, 0.229) \\  
\beta_{\nm{sleep}_5}   & 0.011 & (-0.064, 0.086) & 0.034 & (-0.033, 0.101) \\ 
\beta_{\nm{act}_2}     & 0.135 & ( 0.060, 0.209) & 0.033 & (-0.033, 0.100) \\
\beta_{\nm{act}_3}     & 0.195 & ( 0.121, 0.269) & 0.203 & ( 0.137, 0.268) \\  
\beta_{\nm{act}_4}     & 0.214 & ( 0.139, 0.290) & 0.254 & ( 0.186, 0.321) \\ 
\beta_{\nm{act}_5}     & 0.224 & ( 0.154, 0.294) & 0.158 & ( 0.095, 0.221) \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize$^*$ statistically significant at 5\% level} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Regression Coefficients of model 1 and model 2}\label{beta}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

I've made some notable changes.

1. The subscripts are upright, being words
2. The alignment is improved by using features of the table itself; for instance, the third and fifth column are right aligned because of the minus signs only in the first coordinate; it wouldn't be so if the minus sign appeared also in the second coordinate or the headers had been wider.
3. With `\cmidrule` it's easier to show how the headers group the columns.
4. A trick is used for avoiding the * to take up space.
5. An `array` trick is used for setting all columns in math mode, ensuring that the minus signs are printed as such.
6. `\centering` is used instead of the `center` environment (that adds vertical space).

[image]

If you need to change "95% CI" to "95% Bayesian Interval", the best is to split the long phrase into two lines: modify the block

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coefficient} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{95\% CI}     &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coefficient} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{95\% CI}     \\
\midrule
```

into

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coefficient} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{95\% Bayesian} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coefficient} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{95\% Bayesian} \\
                                & Interval                          &
                                & Interval                          \\
\midrule
```

Comment: I would add a thin `\midrule` between each group of 4 lines, to increase the legibility of the table.

Comment: @tohecz This might be a good idea; it mostly depends on the nature of the data.

Comment: I have deleted my answer since it is just a subset of yours. :)

Comment: @egreg, can you please do me a last favour? I will use this table for the Bayesian intervals as well. So, I exchanged "95 % CI" with "95 % Bayesian intervals". Since "95 % Bayesian intervals" is longer than "95 % CI", the plot skewed to the right. So, what I want to do is to put "intervals" just under "95 % Bayesian". Can you please edit the question for that? Thanks in advance

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question (nor mine).

Comment: @BrandonKuczenski The OP thought differently.

Comment: Then OP asked the wrong question :)

Comment: I'd still really like to know how to fix the vertical line issue instead : / (Can you add a "If you really must do it." section? That would be great!) For me some lines don't hurt to separate content of tables. It sort of seems like many people are only justifying a lack of an easy way of doing that by saying "it looks better without". However, that's subjective.

Comment: @Zelphir Don't use the `booktabs` commands, but `\hline`

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: All this answer accomplished for me was removing my willingness to use the `booktabs` package.

Comment: @Francisco Sorry to hear about this. I find this format for tables much more appealing than jailed ones. There is no need whatsoever for vertical rules.

Comment: @egreg That's your opinion and I respect that, but I completely disagree. Besides, if a package claims to add functionality, it shouldn't be reliant on a subjective criterion such as "this way looks better". When somebody publishes a package, it is only reasonable to assume that their intention is for that particular package to help other people do **what they need**, and not what that particular person thinks is the "right way". That's the way companies like Microsoft do things, not free software people. Sadly I don't have the required ability, so I'll just not use it instead.

Comment: Could you please clarify what does `\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}` mean?
How this column is defferent from `l` except from  warping `$ $` around the text?

Comment: @Temak The text in the cells of that column will be typeset on math mode, so the minus signs will be correct.

Answer (score 85):

I don't think the answer "Don't use vertical rules" is very constructive when the question is about making vertical lines look nice. So here is a solution if you only want to modify the width of horizontal lines and if you are willing to not use booktabs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Parameters  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 2}\\ 
    \noalign{\hrule height 1.5pt}

&  Coefficient & 95\% CI
&   Coefficient & 95\% CI \\ 
    \noalign{\hrule height 1.5pt}

   $\beta_{concern_2}$  &   $0.190^{\ast}$ & (0.113, 0.268) & 0.171 & (0.100, 0.241)\\
   $\beta_{concern_3}$   &  0.117 &  (0.043, 0.191)  & 0.117 & (0.050, 0.183)\\ 
    $\beta_{concern_4}$ & 0.210  &  (0.139, 0.281)  & 0.190 & (0.127, 0.253)\\ 
     $\beta_{concern_5}$ & 0.204 & (0.135, 0.273)   & 0.111 & ( 0.049, 0.173)\\  
    $\beta_{breath_2}$  &  0.157 & (0.07,8 0.236) & 0.208 & (0.136, 0.280) \\
     $\beta_{breath_3}$ & 0.115 & (0.041, 0.189) & 0.100 & (0.034, 0.166) \\
    $\beta_{breath_4}$ & 0.236 &  (0.160, 0.311) & 0.301 & ( 0.234, 0.368)\\  
    $\beta_{breath_5}$ & 0.092 & (0.020, 0.163) & 0.079 & (0.015, 0.144) \\
   $\beta_{weath_2}$  &   0.164 & ( 0.092, 0.236) & 0.137 & (0.071, 0.203) \\
    $\beta_{weath_3}$  & 0.160 &  (0.089, 0.231) & 0.199 & (0.135, 0.263) \\
   $\beta_{weath_4}$ &  0.141 & (0.067, 0.215) & 0.133 & (0.066, 0.199) \\
    $\beta_{weath_5}$ & 0.176 & (0.103, 0.249) &  0.257 & (0.191, 0.323)\\ 
    $\beta_{sleep_2}$  & 0.111 & (0.036, 0.187) & 0.135 & (0.068 0.203)  \\ 
    $\beta_{sleep_3}$  & 0.110 & (0.036 0.184) & 0.176 &  0.110 0.242 \\   
    $\beta_{sleep_4}$  &  0.131 & (0.056 0.205 & 0.162 & 0.095 0.229 \\  
    $\beta_{sleep_5}$  & 0.011 & (-0.064, 0.086) & 0.034 & (-0.033, 0.101) \\ 
    $\beta_{act_2}$ &  0.135 & (0.060, 0.209) & 0.033 & (-0.033, 0.100) \\
    $\beta_{act_3}  $ &0.195 & (0.121, 0.269) & 0.203 & ( 0.137, 0.268)\\  
    $\beta_{act_4}  $ & 0.214 & ( 0.139, 0.290) & 0.254 & (0.186 0.321) \\ 
    $\beta_{act_5}  $ & 0.224 & (0.154, 0.294) & 0.158 & (0.095, 0.221) \\

\hline
    & *statistically significant at 5\% level \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Regression Coefficients of model 1 and model 2 }
\label{beta}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

`\midrule` , `\toprule` , and `\bottomrule` are replaced by `\noalign{\hrule height 1.5pt}` with the width that you want.

You can also set the width of vertical lines by using `!{\vrule width 2pt}` instead of `|` in the tabular parameters.

I understand that this solution is not optimal, but it can do the trick and I hope it would help.

Comment: Wow, I love this solution!! Doesn't require any importing of other library or defining of a new command.

Answer (score 24):

As [@Puck](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/69723/puck) says in his answer, and as [Brandon Kuczenski](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/987/brandon-kuczenski) comments, the responses here are not constructive, neither the question is answered.

The way to use vertical lines with booktabs (despite it is discouraged), is to reduce the space above and below the midrule:

```
 \aboverulesep=0ex
 \belowrulesep=0ex
```

This will cramp your tables a little bit, so, to return to a regular table line height, you should stretch your array with:

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{SF}
```

Where SF is the stretch factor (use SF>1.0).

Just in case, you should add those lines in the preamble.

Hope this does answer your question.

Comment: But using this *solution* makes using `booktabs` very pointless.

Comment: But it *answers* the question ;)

Comment: And, BTW, it's not pointless as you can use `\begin{tabular}{c|c}` together with `\cmidrule{2-2}` if that's the way you want to do it.

Answer (score 10):

booktabs also offers the `specialrule` like so:

```
\specialrule{\cmidrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}
```

which will produce a horizontal line with no spacing and the vertical lines will cross it neatly.

Answer (score 4):

Vertical lines are always continuous with the rules of `booktabs` if you use `tblr` or `talltblr` or `longtblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section{First Solution with \texttt{tblr} Environment}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\toprule
  Parameters & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Model 1 & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Model 2 & \\ 
\midrule
             &  Coefficient & 95\% CI     &  Coefficient & 95\% CI \\ 
\midrule
   $\beta_{concern_2}$ & $0.190^{\ast}$ & (0.113, 0.268) & 0.171 & (0.100, 0.241)\\
   $\beta_{concern_3}$ & 0.117 &  (0.043, 0.191)  & 0.117 & (0.050, 0.183)\\ 
   $\beta_{concern_4}$ & 0.210 &  (0.139, 0.281)  & 0.190 & (0.127, 0.253)\\ 
   $\beta_{concern_5}$ & 0.204 & (0.135, 0.273)   & 0.111 & ( 0.049, 0.173)\\  
   $\beta_{breath_2}$  & 0.157 & (0.07,8 0.236) & 0.208 & (0.136, 0.280) \\
   $\beta_{breath_3}$  & 0.115 & (0.041, 0.189) & 0.100 & (0.034, 0.166) \\
\midrule
    & *Statistically significant at 5\% level \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{Regression Coefficients of model 1 and model 2}
\label{alpha}
\end{table}

\section{Second Solution with \texttt{talltblr} Environment}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{talltblr}[
  caption = {Regression Coefficients of model 1 and model 2},
  label = {beta},
  note{*} = {Statistically significant at 5\% level.},
]{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\toprule
  Parameters & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Model 1 & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Model 2 & \\ 
\midrule
             &  Coefficient & 95\% CI     &  Coefficient & 95\% CI \\ 
\midrule
   $\beta_{concern_2}$ & 0.190\rlap{\TblrNote{*}} & (0.113, 0.268) & 0.171 & (0.100, 0.241)\\
   $\beta_{concern_3}$ & 0.117 &  (0.043, 0.191)  & 0.117 & (0.050, 0.183)\\ 
   $\beta_{concern_4}$ & 0.210 &  (0.139, 0.281)  & 0.190 & (0.127, 0.253)\\ 
   $\beta_{concern_5}$ & 0.204 & (0.135, 0.273)   & 0.111 & ( 0.049, 0.173)\\  
   $\beta_{breath_2}$  & 0.157 & (0.07,8 0.236) & 0.208 & (0.136, 0.280) \\
   $\beta_{breath_3}$  & 0.115 & (0.041, 0.189) & 0.100 & (0.034, 0.166) \\
\bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to follows *user215982*'s suggestion of `\aboverulesep=0ex` and `\belowrulesep=0ex`.  However, I wanted to avoid the gaps between table rows caused by `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.35}`.  Instead, to put back the required vertical spacing, I placed vertical struts `\rule{0pt}{1.1EM}` in the row for the column headings and in the 1st row of data in the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.35} % Not part of my solution
\begin{document}
\begin{table}\centering
   \aboverulesep=0ex % Solution part 1 of 3
   \belowrulesep=0ex % Solution part 1 of 3
   \caption{Example records from a data frame.}
   \begin{tabular}[t]{ccc|ccc}
   \toprule
       \rule{0pt}{1.1EM}% Solution part 2 of 3 (% is required)
       XXXX & XXX\_XXXX & XXXXXX & XXXX & XXX\_XXXX & XXXXXX \\
   \midrule
       \rule{0pt}{1.1EM}% Solution part 3 of 3 (% is required)
       XXXX & XXX       &  XXX   & XXXX & XXX       &  XXX   \\
       XXXX & XXX       &  XXX   & XXXX & XXX       & XXXX   \\
       XXXX & XXX       &  XXX   & XXXX & XXX       &  XXX   \\
       XXXX & XXX       &  XXX   \\
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}

% This just helps visualize the effect of \rule parameters
\rule{3mm}{.1pt}%
\rule[-1mm]{5mm}{1cm}%
\rule{3mm}{.1pt}%
\rule[1mm]{1cm}{5mm}%
\rule{3mm}{.1pt}%
\rule{1cm}{5mm}%
\rule{3mm}{.1pt}

\end{document}
```

The result is what I sought:

[image]

**Please help improve this answer:** My visual inspection seems to confirm that placing the commands `\aboverulesep=0ex` and `\belowrulesep=0ex` between `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` keeps the commands local.  It would help if those more familiar with LaTeX confirm this explicitly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I trimmed it a little, added small spaces between every 4th row, and used short forms for the titles, and right aligned the first column, to tighten it.
[image: cropped table]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}}
\newcommand{\nm}[1]{\textnormal{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}RCRCR@{}}
\toprule
%\multicolumn{1}{r}{Parameter} 
&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1}    &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 2}    \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{Param} 
&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coeff} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{95\% CI}     &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coeff} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{95\% CI}     \\
\midrule
\beta_{\nm{concern}_2} & 0.190\makebox[0pt][l]{$^{\ast}$} 
                           & ( 0.113, 0.268) & 0.171 & ( 0.100, 0.241) \\
\beta_{\nm{concern}_3} & 0.117 & ( 0.043, 0.191) & 0.117 & ( 0.050,0.183) \\ 
\beta_{\nm{concern}_4} & 0.210 & ( 0.139, 0.281) & 0.190 & ( 0.127, 0.253) \\ 
\beta_{\nm{concern}_5} & 0.204 & ( 0.135, 0.273) & 0.111 & ( 0.049, 0.173) \\[4pt]  
\beta_{\nm{breath}_2}  & 0.157 & ( 0.078, 0.236) & 0.208 & ( 0.136, 0.280) \\
\beta_{\nm{breath}_3}  & 0.115 & ( 0.041, 0.189) & 0.100 & ( 0.034, 0.166) \\
\beta_{\nm{breath}_4}  & 0.236 & ( 0.160, 0.311) & 0.301 & ( 0.234, 0.368) \\  
\beta_{\nm{breath}_5}  & 0.092 & ( 0.020, 0.163) & 0.079 & ( 0.015, 0.144) \\[4pt]
\beta_{\nm{weath}_2}   & 0.164 & ( 0.092, 0.236) & 0.137 & ( 0.071, 0.203) \\
\beta_{\nm{weath}_3}   & 0.160 & ( 0.089, 0.231) & 0.199 & ( 0.135, 0.263) \\
\beta_{\nm{weath}_4}   & 0.141 & ( 0.067, 0.215) & 0.133 & ( 0.066, 0.199) \\
\beta_{\nm{weath}_5}   & 0.176 & ( 0.103, 0.249) & 0.257 & ( 0.191, 0.323) \\[4pt] 
\beta_{\nm{sleep}_2}   & 0.111 & ( 0.036, 0.187) & 0.135 & ( 0.068, 0.203) \\ 
\beta_{\nm{sleep}_3}   & 0.110 & ( 0.036, 0.184) & 0.176 & ( 0.110, 0.242) \\   
\beta_{\nm{sleep}_4}   & 0.131 & ( 0.056, 0.205) & 0.162 & ( 0.095, 0.229) \\  
\beta_{\nm{sleep}_5}   & 0.011 & (-0.064, 0.086) & 0.034 & (-0.033, 0.101) \\[4pt] 
\beta_{\nm{act}_2}     & 0.135 & ( 0.060, 0.209) & 0.033 & (-0.033, 0.100) \\
\beta_{\nm{act}_3}     & 0.195 & ( 0.121, 0.269) & 0.203 & ( 0.137, 0.268) \\  
\beta_{\nm{act}_4}     & 0.214 & ( 0.139, 0.290) & 0.254 & ( 0.186, 0.321) \\ 
\beta_{\nm{act}_5}     & 0.224 & ( 0.154, 0.294) & 0.158 & ( 0.095, 0.221) \\

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize$^*$ statistically significant at 5\% level} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Regression Coefficients of model 1 and model 2}\label{beta}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want vertical rules compatible with the rules of `booktabs` (which is not at all in the spirit of `booktabs`), you should use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}

 \begin{document}

\begin{table} [h!]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\toprule
Parameters  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 2}\\ 
\midrule

&  Coefficient & 95\% CI
&   Coefficient & 95\% CI \\ 
    \midrule

   $\beta_{concern_2}$  &   $0.190$\tabularnote{statistically significant at 5\% level}& (0.113, 0.268) & 0.171 & (0.100, 0.241)\\
   $\beta_{concern_3}$   &  0.117 &  (0.043, 0.191)  & 0.117 & (0.050, 0.183)\\ 
    $\beta_{concern_4}$ & 0.210  &  (0.139, 0.281)  & 0.190 & (0.127, 0.253)\\ 
     $\beta_{concern_5}$ & 0.204 & (0.135, 0.273)   & 0.111 & ( 0.049, 0.173)\\  
    $\beta_{breath_2}$  &  0.157 & (0.07,8 0.236) & 0.208 & (0.136, 0.280) \\
     $\beta_{breath_3}$ & 0.115 & (0.041, 0.189) & 0.100 & (0.034, 0.166) \\
    $\beta_{breath_4}$ & 0.236 &  (0.160, 0.311) & 0.301 & ( 0.234, 0.368)\\  
    $\beta_{breath_5}$ & 0.092 & (0.020, 0.163) & 0.079 & (0.015, 0.144) \\
   $\beta_{weath_2}$  &   0.164 & ( 0.092, 0.236) & 0.137 & (0.071, 0.203) \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Regression Coefficients of model 1 and model 2 }
\label{beta}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]