# In a table how do I add vertical lines between each column?

Tags: tables, rules, booktabs

I have this as my current table which is fine, but I would like there to be vertical lines too just to make it look that bit neater. 
I'd also like horizontal lines between each row but this would require resizing the rows to avoid the fractions on the right column clashing with the line?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
    \bfseries $f(t)$ & 
    \bfseries $\Lap[f(t)]$\\
    \midrule
    $k$ & $\frac ks$ \\ $e^{at}$ & $\frac{1}{s-a}$ \\ $\sin{(at)}$ & $\frac{a}{s^2+a^2}$ \\ $\cos{(at)}$ & $\frac{s}{s^2+a^2}$ \\ $t^n$ & $\frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}$ \\ $\sinh{(at)}$ & $\frac{a}{s^2-a^2}$ \\ $\cosh{(at)}$ & $\frac{s}{s^2-a^2}$ \\
    \bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Do you mean somethin like ``\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}``?

Comment: Vertical rules doesn't work well with `booktabs`, see the [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/booktabs) or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88929/vertical-table-lines-are-discontinuous-with-booktabs. With `\midrule`s you won't get any clashing, by the way.

Comment: @ChristianR. This won't really work acceptably with `booktabs`. The `booktabs` documentation has some very good arguments about why for most tables, vertical lines are not appropriate.  See e.g. [Vertical lines are discontinuous with booktabs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88929/2693).

Comment: Exactly that for the vertical! Thank you. I also added a \midrule after every line and I'll try printing to see if the lines meet as the PDF suggests they don't.

Comment: @AlanMunn You are absolutely right, I overlooked the use of booktabs.

Comment: There is no use loading booktabs if you want vertical lines, the package explicitly introduces constructs that are incompatible with vertical lines and documents that vertical lines are evil. So If you want vertical lines (which are not always evil:-) use the standard latex `\hline`  for horizontal lines.

Comment: There is a `booktabs` tag but I don't think the OP added it. If this is true, it's not clear if references to `booktabs` are relevant. @DannyBland Please turn your code into a minimal working example so we can see the context.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen The presence of `\toprule`, `\midrule` entails `booktabs` use. (But I agree that Danny should turn this into a compilable example.)

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks. I had overlooked `\toprule` and friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a table containing only formulas it might be easier to use the `array` environment, which needs to be in `math-mode` (here `displaymath`). If you want to use verticle lines, you shouldn't use `booktabs`, simply use `\hline` instead.

The most of the following code is self-explanatory, but maybe not `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}`, which is used to widen the rowheight, because otherwise the fractures will touch the lines.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{displaymath}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\mathbf{f(t)} & \mathbf{\textbf{Lap}[f(t)]} \\ \hline \hline
k             & \frac ks           \\ \hline
e^{at}        & \frac{1}{s-a}      \\ \hline
\sin{(at)}    & \frac{a}{s^2+a^2}  \\ \hline
\cos{(at)}    & \frac{s}{s^2+a^2}  \\ \hline
t^n           & \frac{n!}{s^{n+1}} \\ \hline
\sinh{(at)}   & \frac{a}{s^2-a^2}  \\ \hline
\cosh{(at)}   & \frac{s}{s^2-a^2}  \\ \hline
\end{array}
\end{displaymath}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: This is very badly vertically positioned. It seems to me that `\arraystretch` isn't the right way to go here...