# Discontinuous line using \multirow

Tags: tables, border

I've been struggling with table editing, so I started using a website to generate tables in LaTeX. However, whenever I'm using multirow and borders, things get a little tricky. I get a discontinuous line along my column.

As a test, I'm using this:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c|cc@{}}
Test               & a & b \\ \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{x} & 1 & 2 \\ \cmidrule(l){2-3} 
               & 3 & 4
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This is the result:

[image: test table]

I'm using TexPortable with MiKTeX 2.9.6210 and Texmaker 4.5.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88929/134144

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to the padding around horizontal lines in `booktabs` (the lengths `\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep`). Vertical rules should not be used with `booktabs` in general (this principle suffers exceptions). A workaround consists in setting them to 0 and replacing them with more or less equivalent lengths added at the top and bottom of cells with the tools from `makecell`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, array, makecell, caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c|cc@{}}
Test & a & b \\ \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{x} & 1 & 2 \\ \addlinespace[-0.03em]\cmidrule(l){2-3}
               & 3 & 4
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried that and it worked on the vertical line, but the horizontal line is still discontinuous, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o5lR.png). Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean the short line between 2nd and 3rd row? I thought it was there purposely. The responsible is the `(l)` optional argument of `\cmidrule`.  Just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want vertical lines compatible with the horizontal rules of `booktabs`, you should use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption, nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}c|cc@{}}[cell-space-limits=3pt]
Test & a & b \\ \midrule
\Block{2-1}{x} & 1 & 2 \\ \cmidrule(l){2-3}
               & 3 & 4
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]