# How i make like this table?

Tags: tables

I'm preparing my thesis and i came across this problem ! the truth is that latex is new to me and i tried my best to make this table but i'm working against time now. can any one please made this table for me ?
[image: figure]

thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! There are plenty of similar tables on this site. Please adapt one of them, try to modify it to your needs, and if you get stuck, you'll have an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that makes it much more likely that you get a good answer.

Comment: [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) should be a good point to start. But please note: This is not a *Do It for Me*-Service.

Comment: If you are short of time, I recommend that you use a system type what you see is what you get, such as free office or open office, take a screenshot, and include it in your document using the `graphicx` package, since you should not have time like to look for thousands of examples of tables on this site like this [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88939/154390) for example.

Comment: You can take a look at [TeX Consulting and Production Services](https://www.tug.org/consultants.html) to find people who will do such things for you (for money of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for those who answered me, although i didn't find my request so i kept searching and i came across this tool it called excel to latex. basically it trensfer any table in excel to latex code..
this the results..
link to the tool
https://www.ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex?lang=en

[image: excel to latex]

and here the table in latex

[image: table in latex]

Hope it helped any body here.

Salam

Comment: The table has five columns, the converter produced seven. Never trust a converter.

Comment: Actually i make 7 columns if you noticed in Excel ! Only to get that extra space between main columns