# Reducing the gap around the frames of longtable

Tags: longtable, gap

When creating a long table, The following conflict occured in line of tables.

[image]

I need to fix it and make it a complete frame around the table.

I used the following codes in order to make a longtable.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,onesided,12pt]{report}


\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % To use Unicode (e.g. Turkish) characters    
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}    
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}    
 % Some extra symbols    
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}    
\usepackage{cite}    
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\usepackage{longtable}    
\usepackage{multirow}    
\usepackage{subfigure}    
\usepackage{algorithm}    
\usepackage{algorithmic}    
\newlength{\mycolumnwidth}    
\setlength{\mycolumnwidth}{\textwidth-9cm-4\tabcolsep}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|m{9cm}|m{\mycolumnwidth}|}    
\caption{Tarık's emergent codes and corresponding themes}\\    
\toprule    
 RELEVANT CODES &   THEME \\    
 \toprule
 \endfirsthead 

\caption{Tarık's emergent codes and corresponding themes (continued)}\\    
\toprule
RELEVANT CODES &   THEME \\ 
\hline     
\endhead    

Graph representation & \multirow{1}{*}{Interpretation of graph} \\     
Graph completion & \\ 
\midrule    
Thinking about quadratic functions & \\     
Thinking about quadratic functions in real life 
& \multirow{1}{*}{Interpretation of function} \\     
Thinking about quadratic functions in physics & \\    
\midrule    
Finding a satisfactory answer to what question requires 
&\multirow{1}{*}{Make sense of model repr.}  \\ 
\midrule    
\pagebreak   
Looking interaction between his drawn model and given graph 
&\multirow{1}{*}{Alignment of model-graph} \\ 
Finding conflict when matching his graph and his  model & \\  
\bottomrule

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The given code does not compile as we do not know the content of the `fbe_tez` style file. Please make a real MWE from your code. By the way: Your given code does not match the shown output.

Comment: The horizontal rules from the `booktabs` package (`\toprule`, `\midrule`) are incompatible with vertical lines as discussed here: [Vertical table lines are discontinuous with booktabs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88929/134144)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Booktabs` adds some padding around its rules, which is the cause of the non-intersecting horizontal and vertical lines. If you want them to intersect, and nevertheless have rules with varying thickness, you can either  use another package such as `boldline` or `makecell`, or you deactivate the padding of rules in `booktabs`, and partly replacing it with an `\extrarowheight`.

I propose a code with the latter solution. In addition, I changed the code to have a single row between two horizontal rules, which is easy since the cells are in paragraph mode and results in a normal line spacing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,onesided,12pt]{report}

%\usepackage{styles/fbe_tez}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % To use Unicode (e.g. Turkish) characters
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
 % Some extra symbols
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable, multirow}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{algorithm, algorithmic}
\newlength{\mycolumnwidth}
\setlength{\mycolumnwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-9cm-4\tabcolsep}
\newcommand*{\nl}{\newline}

\begin{document}

\begingroup\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{longtable}{| m{9cm}| >{\arraybackslash\RaggedRight}m{\dimexpr\textwidth-9cm-4\tabcolsep}|}
\caption{Tarık's emergent codes and corresponding themes}\\
\toprule
 RELEVANT CODES & THEME \\
 \toprule
 \endfirsthead

\caption{Tarık's emergent codes and corresponding themes (continued)}\\
\toprule
RELEVANT CODES & THEME \\
\hline
\endhead

Graph representation \nl Graph completion & Interpretation of graph \\
\midrule 
Thinking about quadratic functions \nl
Thinking about quadratic functions in real life \nl
Thinking about quadratic functions in physics 
& Interpretation of function \\ 
\midrule
Finding a satisfactory answer to what question requires
& Make sense of model repr. \\
\midrule
\pagebreak
Looking interaction between his drawn model and given graph \nl
Finding conflict when matching his graph and his model 
& Alignment of model-graph \\ 
\bottomrule

\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]