# How to replace the **first** `@{}` as `@{ \extracolsep{\fill} }`

Tags: tables

I just want to replace the **first** `@{}` as `@{ \extracolsep{\fill} }` show in **MWE's comment**.
When try to use `\patchcmd`, it failed!

You know, I have a lot of this style table in my document. So want to some automatic code to do this patch work.

Thanks a lot in advance!

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}       
\setlength\LTright{0pt}   

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}llll@{}}
%\begin{longtable}[]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llll@{}}
\caption{\label{tab:simple-table} A Table}\tabularnewline
\toprule
Name & Income & Job & Color \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Name & Income & Job & Color \\
\midrule
\endhead
Jane & 123456 & Research Assistant & red \\
John & 50 & N/A & blue \\
William & 3200 & Cleaner & blue \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it woul be better to change your source than use a tex patch. also it wouldnt matter if you changed them all having two identical settings makes no difference

Comment: 1)The source `.tex` is produced from pandoc. 2)Both replace the `@{ }` as the same `@{ \extracolsep{\fill} }` also ok, but HOW to do this patch?

Comment: you must presumably be specifying somewhere the tabular preamble `llll` ?  (I don't have pandoc installed)

Comment: I just use `pandoc.exe` to convert the `.markdown` to `.tex`. You know, the other tables may be have different tabular, such as `rcclll` or `cccrrrrrrrrrrrlll`, not fixed settings.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595615/how-can-i-reformat-a-table-using-markdown-pandoc-pdf

Comment: @David Carlisle This link is very usefull. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. At any rate, I'd say that in addition to modifying the argument of the `\begin{longtable}` directive, you should also provide `\endfoot` and `\endlastfoot` directives and consider using an `S` column type for the second column, so that the numbers can be aligned on their respective (implied) decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,siunitx}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}       
\setlength\LTright{0pt}   

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
                  l
                  S[table-format=6.0,group-minimum-digits=4]
                  ll @{}}

%% headers and footers:

\caption{A Table} \label{tab:simple-table} \\
\toprule
Name & {Income} & Job & Color \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\tablename\ \thetable, continued}\\[0.5ex]
\toprule
Name & {Income} & Job & Color \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{\small (continued on following page)} \\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot


%% body of table:

Jane & 123456 & Research Assistant & red \\
John & 50 & N/A & blue \\
William & 3200 & Cleaner & blue \\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```