# Vertical lines connecting in latex tables - agujournal2018 cls

Tags: tables, spacing, rules

I am using the agujournal2018 cls files (available [here](https://publications.agu.org/author-resource-center/checklists-and-templates/)).  To make it easier while I am drafting, I want lines in tables.  How can I make the vertical lines and horizontal lines connect in tables?

I tried to use the `\aboverulesep=0ex`
 `\belowrulesep=0ex` answer relevant to booktabs [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88929/vertical-table-lines-are-discontinuous-with-booktabs) with no luck

MWE

```
\documentclass[draft]{agujournal2018}
\usepackage{apacite}

\usepackage{url} %this package should fix any errors with URLs in refs.
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
%%%%%%%

\draftfalse

\journalname{Enter journal name here}
\begin{document}

 \begin{table}
 \caption{Time of the Transition Between Phase 1 and Phase 2$^{a}$}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{l  | c}
 \hline
  Run  & Time (min)  \\
 \hline
   $l1$  & 260   \\
   $l2$  & 300   \\
   $l3$  & 340   \\
   $h1$  & 270   \\
   $h2$  & 250   \\
   $h3$  & 380   \\
   $r1$  & 370   \\
   $r2$  & 390   \\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{l}{$^{a}$Footnote text here.}
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

I realise that the journal doesn't have these lines and I will need to remove them before submitting, but it will make drafting a LOT easier if can lay the tables out with lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`agujournal2018.cls`](https://publications.agu.org/files/2018/08/August-23-2018-latex-templates.zip) document class mentions this:

```
  %% This puts extra space between horizontal lines in tables.
  %% If you want to use vertical lines in tables, you should use
  %% \savehline rather than \hline, otherwise the vertical and
  %% horizontal lines will not abutt.

  %% \noalign is a command that allows the uses to put something
  %% between lines in a table.
\let\savehline\hline
\def\hline{\noalign{\vskip3pt}\savehline\noalign{\vskip3pt}}
```

So, you can use `\savehline` rather than `\hline`, or use this construction:

[image]

```
\let\savedhline\hline % Store default \hline
\documentclass{agujournal2018}
\let\hline\savedhline % Restore default \hline

\journalname{Enter journal name here}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{A caption}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l  | c}
    \hline
    Run  & Time (min)  \\
    \hline
    $l1$  & 260   \\
    $l2$  & 300   \\
    $l3$  & 340   \\
    $h1$  & 270   \\
    $h2$  & 250   \\
    $h3$  & 380   \\
    $r1$  & 370   \\
    $r2$  & 390   \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```