# How to add the cross vertical line in two column table

Tags: tables

how to add the cross vertical line in two column table.
There should be cross vertical line in below. 
My code is starting like this:

```
\begin{table*}[t]
\centering
\caption{cap}
\scalebox{0.67}{
\begin{tabular}{c|ccc|ccc|ccc}
\toprule
kk & 1  & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1  & 2 & 3 \\
\midrule
name & \multicolumn{3}{c}{aa} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{bb} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{cc} \\
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The rules from `booktabs` do  not cooperate well with vertical lines. So either remove the vertical lines (as suggestet in the `booktabs` manual) or use different horizontal lines. [Vertical table lines are discontinuous with booktabs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88929/134144) might be interested.

Comment: the output you show is from booktabs that you do not mention, please read the booktabs documentation, it intentionally does not support vertical rules. Also navoid using `\scalebox` with tables it will produce inconsistent font sizes and rule widths,