# gap between toprule and vertical lines in tabular

Tags: tables, booktabs

In this MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}%added 8/16/2019
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.5ex}

\begin{document}            
\small
\begin{tabular}[c]{|p{1.5in}|p{4in}|}
\toprule
Problem&1\\\hline 
ODE            &${\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x \right) =1+2\,x$\\\hline 
ODE degree     &1\\\hline 
Number of solutions &1\\\hline 
CAS classification &quadrature\\\hline 
Program classification&{\footnotesize [separable]}\\\hline 
Solved? &yes\\\hline
Verified? &yes\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\normalsize

\end{document}
```

I need to close the gap shown in the output:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How to modify the above MWE to close these gaps?

Using TL 2019

Comment: That's quite by design. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88929/82917. Might actually be a duplicate.

Comment: This is by design, in general vertical lines serves no purpose in data tables. They only makes the data more difficult to read (because your eyes have a tendency to follow the vertical lines, thus you have to concentrate harder to read a line with vertical lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different approach using `\Xhline` from the `makecell` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{makecell}


\begin{document}

\small
\begin{tabular}[c]{|p{1.5in}|p{4in}|}
\Xhline{0.5ex}
Problem&1\\\hline 
ODE            &${\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x \right) =1+2\,x$\\\hline 
ODE degree     &1\\\hline 
Number of solutions &1\\\hline 
CAS classification &quadrature\\\hline 
Program classification&{\footnotesize [separable]}\\\hline 
Solved? &yes\\\hline
Verified? &yes\\ 
\Xhline{0.5ex}
\end{tabular}
\normalsize

\end{document}
```

---

An example using the `booktabs` package and following the guidelines from the `booktabs` manual

> You will not go far wrong if you remember two simple guidelines at all
>   times: 1.  Never, ever use vertical rules.

could look like the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[c]{ll}
\midrule
Problem & 1 \\ \addlinespace
ODE            &${\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x \right) =1+2\,x$\\ \addlinespace
ODE degree     &1\\  \addlinespace
Number of solutions &1\\ \addlinespace
CAS classification &quadrature\\ \addlinespace
Program classification&{\footnotesize [separable]}\\  \addlinespace
Solved? &yes\\ \addlinespace
Verified? &yes\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```