# Tabular disjoint line

Tags: tables

I am using the tabular function to create my table but the line that comes out seems to be disconnected. How do I fix this without changing the function ? I still need to use tabular.

```
\begin{table}
\centering
 \subfloat{%
   \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \toprule
    A & 0.002s \\ 
    B & 0.05s \\
    C & \\ \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
 }
 \caption{}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Lines from the booktabs package are intended to be used without vertical lines.

Comment: you should always  provide a test document not a fragment. This is purely a question about booktabs (which you do not mention) booktabs _by design_ makes vertical rules unusable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88939/231952, it is not a good idea to use vertical rules in tables. In any case, to answer your question, these commands will suffice:

```
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
```

Table 1. With `booktabs` and without vertical rules (best choice):

```
\begin{tabular}{cc} \toprule
    A & 0.002s \\ 
    B & 0.05s \\
    C & \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Table 2. Without `booktabs` (i.e. with standard rules):

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
    A & 0.002s \\ 
    B & 0.05s \\
    C & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Table 3. With vertical rules and `booktabs`:

```
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \toprule
A & 0.002s \\ 
B & 0.05s \\
C & \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: You should compensate the lack of vertical padding of horizontal rules in the last two solutions, say with `cellspace`.

Answer (score 4):

If you actually want to draw vertical rules compatible with the rules of booktabs (`\toprule`, `bottomrule`, `\midrule`, etc.), although this is not at all in the spirit of `booktabs`, you should use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
   \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|} \toprule
    A & 0.002s \\ 
    B & 0.05s \\
    C & \\ \bottomrule
   \end{NiceTabular}
\caption{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned tables rules defined in the `booktabs` are not intended for use with vertical lines.

If you like to have table where vertical in horizontal rules are connected and also horizontal have different thickness and some vertical distance from cells' contents, you can achieve this by use of the `makecell` package which provide a way to add more vertical space around cells contents as well to define horizontal rules of different thickness:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells    % <---
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} 
    \Xhline{1pt}       % <---
A & 0.002s \\
B & 0.05s \\
C & \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabular}
\caption{My lovely table}
\label{tab:mlt}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]