# Why table lines not right (multicolumn, multirow?)

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

I have used the code below to produce a table, however, it does not look correct. The regions that are causing issue are circled in red. Are the multicolumn/multirow packages not working in sync with tabular? Any suggestions to fix these issues?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{boldline}

\begin{table}[b!]
    \caption{.}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}%
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.45pt}
\begin{tabular}{l c || c c c | c c c | c c} % 
\hlineB{2}
\multirow{3}{*}{} & \multirow{3}{*}{Year} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Technique}   &  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Type}   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Detail}\\
          &   & \multirow{2}{*}{Type}  &$\tau$ & \multirow{2}{*}{Idea}   & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\bar{u}$}   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Idea}\\
    &   &  & [$-$] & &  $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & 1 & 2  \\ \hline \hline
& 2020 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\ 
\hlineB{2}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

Since the answers refer to the original code of this question, it is provided here for reference. The above code has been edited by the OP.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[b!]
    \caption{.}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.45pt}
\begin{tabular}{l c || c c c | c c c | c c} 
\toprule
        \multirow{3}{*}{} & \multirow{3}{*}{Year} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Technique}   &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Type}   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Detail}\\
          &   & \multirow{2}{*}{Type}  &$\tau$ & \multirow{2}{*}{Idea}   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\bar{u}$}   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Idea}\\
    &   &  & [$-$] & &  $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & 1 & 2  \\ \hline \hline
& 2020 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The fact that you use `\toprule` suggests that you are loading `booktabs`, and `booktabs` simply does not like vertical rules, see [Vertical table lines are discontinuous with booktabs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88929/82917).

Comment: A single vertical rule is bad, a double vertical rule is… ;-) Just don't use them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, if you want vertical rules, you [should not use the `booktabs` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88929/82917) and stick to the regular `\hline` macro.

Also, if you use `multicol`s, you need to tell them in the column definition that you want to have a vertical rule. So, instead of `\multicolumn{3}{c}{...}`, you should write `\multicolumn{3}{c|}{...}` where appropriate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[b!]
\caption{.}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.45pt}
\begin{tabular}{l c || c c c | c c c | c c} 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{} & \multirow{3}{*}{Year} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Technique} &  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Type} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Detail} \\
 &  & \multirow{2}{*}{Type} & $\tau$ & \multirow{2}{*}{Idea} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\bar{u}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Idea} \\
 &  &  & [$-$] & &  $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & 1 & 2  \\ \hline \hline
 & 2020 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! This is almost perfect -- is there anyway of emulating the \toprule and \bottomrule line thickness using \hline?

Comment: @jrjr: you have the `\Xhline` and `\Xcline` commands from `makecell`, or `\hlineB` and `\clineB` form `boldline` (`shipunov` bundle`).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I have updated the code and figure attached -- I am still getting an issue (as highlighted by the red circles). Do you know how to fix that? thanks

Comment: Please keep your original problem with picture and code in your question (you may add an additional question if related), because otherwise the answers are of no help for others who may have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to use vertical rules with the horizontal rules of `booktabs` (which is not at all in the spirit of `\booktabs`), you should use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[b!]
\caption{My Caption}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.45pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c || c c c | c c c | c c} 
\toprule
& \Block{1-3}{Technique} &&&  \Block{1-3}{Type} &&& \Block{1-2}{Detail} \\
Year & \Block{2-1}{Type} & $\tau$ & \Block{2-1}{Idea} & \Block{1-3}{$\bar{u}$} &&& \Block{1-2}{Idea} \\
&  & [$-$] & &  $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & 1 & 2  \\ 
\hline\hline
2020 & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]