# How to draw a vertical line in a table?

Tags: tables, nicematrix

How do I draw a vertical line in the following table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{lp{1.5in}lp{1.5in}}
\toprule
Parameter & Description & Parameter & Description\\
\midrule
$A$ & Recruitment rate of the population & $B$ & Transmission coefficient\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In other words I'm trying to get something like the following

parameter     meaning | parameter     meaning

a    pressure| b volatility

c    constant| t time

**EDIT:**

I tried:

```
\noindent\begin{NiceTabular}{lp{1.5in}|lp{1.5in}}
    \toprule
    Parameter & Description & Parameter & Description\\
    \midrule
    $\mu$ & Influx rate of the population & $\epsilon$ & Progression rate from $I_1$ to $I_2$ \\
    $\beta_1$ & Transmission rate of the fast latent compartment & $p_1$ & Progression rate from $I_2$ to $J$ \\
    $\beta_2$ & Transmission rate of the symptomatic compartment & $p_2$ & Progression rate from $J$ to $A$ \\
    $\beta_3$ & Transmission rate of the AIDS compartment & $\xi_1$ & Treatment rate from $J$ to $I_1$ \\
    $p$ & Fraction of S infected by $I_2$ who enter $I_1$ & $\xi_2$ & Treatment rate from $J$ to $I_2$ \\
    $q$ & Fraction of S infected by $J$ who enter $I_1$ & $\nu$ & Natural death rate \\
    $r$ & Fraction of S infected by $A$ who enter $I_1$ & $\alpha$ & Disease related death rate \\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
```

It gave me an error

**EDIT 2 :**

Zarko, can you compile the following code in your solution so I can use it as an image in my document :

```
\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {| Q[c,$] X[l] |
                                   Q[c,$] X[l] |},
                       row{1} = {mode=text},
                     row{2-Y} = {belowsep+=2pt}
                     } 
    \toprule
Parameter & Approximate value & Parameter & Approximate value\\
    \midrule
\mu     & 0.55 
            & \epsilon  & 0.002  \\
\beta_1 & 0.0001 
            & p_1       & 0.01    \\
\beta_2 & 0.006 
            & p_2       & 0.03      \\
\beta_3 & 0.0007 
            & \xi_1     & Varying      \\
p       & Varying 
            & \xi_2     & Varying      \\
q       & Varying 
            & \nu       & 0.01                    \\
r       & Varying 
            & \alpha    & 0.01            \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
```

***EDIT 3***:

Using the pdf version of your code compared to actually compiling the code:

[image]

The pdf one looks far better as its less "bulky", so how can I achieve this?

Comment: you can use `|` but it will be broken at the bookatb rules. Read the booktabs manual for the rules on using vertical rules in tables,

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88929/47927

Comment: the edit does not provide a usable test document so we can not run what you did and you have given no indication of what error or output that you got.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It said `! LaTeX Error: Environment NiceTabular undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.3155  \noindent\begin{NiceTabular}` But I already loaded the package

Comment: you need to load a new enough nicematrix package  or just believe the booktabs manual that stresses that vertical lines are an evil that should never be inflicted on the reader.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle how do I do that?

Comment: that depends. If you have texlive 2021 or miktex just update your tex distribution, if you have an older texlive (I don't now when nicetabular was added) you either need to install a newer tex distribution or just get nicematrix from ctan and install it locally

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using TeXworks

Comment: given that the booktabs manual says "1. Never, ever use vertical rules."  it is slightly odd to choose to use that package and then require vertical rules.

Comment: texworks is just the editor you use to write the file, it's not involved here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using MikTex 2.9 and this was a code given from a different question.

Comment: I don't use miktex but it should have a version of nicematrix that defines nicetabular I am assuming you did run the document in Simon's answer that loaded the package Make sure you have updated miktex in user and admin modes if you have both

Comment: show the log that you get from Simon's document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What do you mean by log? i got this error `! LaTeX Error: Environment NiceTabular undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.3155  \noindent\begin{NiceTabular}
                                    {lp{1.5in}|lp{1.5in}}`

Comment: @Math Open MikTeX console, go to the Packages tab and scroll down to the `nicematrix` package and see if it is installed. If not, right click on it and install it. https://imgur.com/a/SrSngLS

Comment: there will be a file xxx.log generated by tex if your document is xxx.tex  if you showed the full log (rather than the fragment of a document that you currently show) it would for example show the location and version number of the nicematrix package you are using

Comment: @Imran its installed by admin

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't have the log file because of the error, it hasn't compiled it

Comment: No that is not how tex works. It writes the error mesages to the log file. Mkae sure you are usng ppdftex directly not the texify thing that may remove files that you need (I hear)

Comment: I don't see any log files in my documents for any documents

Comment: im using pdfLatex+maketex+bibtex

Comment: @Math Run only with `PDFLaTeX` to generate a log file.

Comment: @Imran I still don't have a log file.  I only have  `.aux`, `.text` and `GZ` files

Comment: I will try again tomorrow or maybe next week.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATED** After follow-up question: solutions do not compile. (see bellow)

Vertical lines can be drawn without conflict with `booktabs` using the `nicematrix` package.

The second table has a better alignment of the cells.  Uses `X` columns to adjust their relative widths and centering.

The only package needed to add is `nicematrix` https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix?lang=en

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{nicematrix} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}


\noindent\begin{NiceTabular}{lp{1.5in}|lp{1.5in}}
    \toprule
    Parameter & Description & Parameter & Description\\
    \midrule
    $\mu$ & Influx rate of the population & $\epsilon$ & Progression rate from $I_1$ to $I_2$ \\
    $\beta_1$ & Transmission rate of the fast latent compartment & $p_1$ & Progression rate from $I_2$ to $J$ \\
    $\beta_2$ & Transmission rate of the symptomatic compartment & $p_2$ & Progression rate from $J$ to $A$ \\
    $\beta_3$ & Transmission rate of the AIDS compartment & $\xi_1$ & Treatment rate from $J$ to $I_1$ \\
    $p$ & Fraction of S infected by $I_2$ who enter $I_1$ & $\xi_2$ & Treatment rate from $J$ to $I_2$ \\
    $q$ & Fraction of S infected by $J$ who enter $I_1$ & $\nu$ & Natural death rate \\
    $r$ & Fraction of S infected by $A$ who enter $I_1$ & $\alpha$ & Disease related death rate \\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\bigskip

    \noindent\begin{NiceTabular}[width=\textwidth]{|X[c,m] X[2,l,m] | X[c,m] X[2,l,m] |}[cell-space-limits=3pt]
    \toprule
    Parameter & Description & Parameter & Description\\
    \midrule
    $\mu$ & Influx rate of the population & $\epsilon$ & Progression rate from $I_1$ to $I_2$ \\
    $\beta_1$ & Transmission rate of the fast latent compartment & $p_1$ & Progression rate from $I_2$ to $J$ \\
    $\beta_2$ & Transmission rate of the symptomatic compartment & $p_2$ & Progression rate from $J$ to $A$ \\
    $\beta_3$ & Transmission rate of the AIDS compartment & $\xi_1$ & Treatment rate from $J$ to $I_1$ \\
    $p$ & Fraction of S infected by $I_2$ who enter $I_1$ & $\xi_2$ & Treatment rate from $J$ to $I_2$ \\
    $q$ & Fraction of S infected by $J$ who enter $I_1$ & $\nu$ & Natural death rate \\
    $r$ & Fraction of S infected by $A$ who enter $I_1$ & $\alpha$ & Disease related death rate \\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

To try the last version of `nicematrix` **without** installing it:

1. Download `nicematrix.zip`  from [nicematrix.zip](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix.zip)
2. Extract  the directory `nicematrix`.
3. Open a command windows  in that directory and execute  `pdflatex nicematrix.ins`.
4. The file `nicematrix.sty` will be generated.
5. Copy that file to your working directory and compile your table

**UPDATE**  Check the version of the packages

Try this code to check the version of the packages

The output will produce two very similar tables, the first using `tabularray` (from Zarko's answer) and the second with `nicematrix`

[image: x]

```
    \documentclass{article}     
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{tabularray} 
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
    \usepackage{nicematrix}
            
    \begin{document}
        \parindent0pt
        
        {\large \textbf{tabularray}}\bigskip    
        
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} Q[c,$] X[l] |
            Q[c,$] X[l] @{}},
        row{1} = {mode=text},
        row{2-Y} = {belowsep+=2pt}
    }  
    \toprule
    Parameter & Description & Parameter & Description\\
    \midrule
    \mu     & Influx rate of the popu\-la\-tion 
    & \epsilon  & Progression rate from $I_1$ to $I_2$  \\
    \beta_1 & Transmission rate of the fast latent compartment 
    & p_1       & Progression rate from $I_2$ to $J$    \\
    \beta_2 & Transmission rate of the symptomatic compartment 
    & p_2       & Progression rate from $J$ to $A$      \\
    \beta_3 & Transmission rate of the AIDS compartment 
    & \xi_1     & Treatment rate from $J$ to $I_1$      \\
    p       & Fraction of S infected by $I_2$ who enter $I_1$ 
    & \xi_2     & Treatment rate from $J$ to $I_2$      \\
    q       & Fraction of S infected by $J$ who enter $I_1$ 
    & \nu       & Natural death rate                    \\
    r       & Fraction of S infected by $A$ who enter $I_1$ 
    & \alpha    & Disease related death rate            \\
    \bottomrule     
\end{tblr}      

\bigskip    

{\large \textbf{nicematrix}}\bigskip

\begin{NiceTabular}{cp{2.0in}|cp{2.0in}}[cell-space-limits=4pt]
    \toprule
    Parameter & Description & Parameter & Description\\
    \midrule
    $\mu$ & Influx rate of the population & $\epsilon$ & Progression rate from $I_1$ to $I_2$ \\
    $\beta_1$ & Transmission rate of the fast latent compartment & $p_1$ & Progression rate from $I_2$ to $J$ \\
    $\beta_2$ & Transmission rate of the symptomatic compartment & $p_2$ & Progression rate from $J$ to $A$ \\
    $\beta_3$ & Transmission rate of the AIDS compartment & $\xi_1$ & Treatment rate from $J$ to $I_1$ \\
    $p$ & Fraction of S infected by $I_2$ who enter $I_1$ & $\xi_2$ & Treatment rate from $J$ to $I_2$ \\
    $q$ & Fraction of S infected by $J$ who enter $I_1$ & $\nu$ & Natural death rate \\
    $r$ & Fraction of S infected by $A$ who enter $I_1$ & $\alpha$ & Disease related death rate \\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document
```

If it fails run the following code

```
    \listfiles % list the files loaded <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \documentclass{article}     
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{tabularray} 
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
    \usepackage{nicematrix}
            
    \begin{document}
        
        Only to list the files loaded

    \end{document}
```

**Important** See that before `\documentclass{article}` there is the command `\listfiles`

Now look at the end of the `.log` file.

You should see a list of all files loaded, similar to

```
*File List*
article.cls    2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo    2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
geometry.sty    2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
....

epstopdf-base.sty    2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
***********
```

On my current system  it appears

```
tabularray.sty    2021-12-01 v2021Q Typeset tabulars and arrays with LaTeX3

nicematrix.sty    2021/09/09 v6.2 Enhanced arrays with the help of PGF/TikZ
```

If in your case the versions installed are previous, I suggest you update them.

I am using the MiKTeX distribution, where this task is done using the MiKTeX Console.

**Edit 2**

[image: di21]

[image: c]

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Check Edit.

Comment: Can you add vertical lines at the beginning and at the end in the second table?

Comment: @Math  I did. Also added some instructions to try the package without installing it.

Comment: I get this error running the last code: `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \l_keys_key_str 
                           
l.4612 ...ormal } { Continued ~ on ~ next ~ page }
                                                  
? `

Comment: @Math  The message is coming from tabularray.  Check the version you have installed. I also get `pdflatex: security risk: running with elevated privileges
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3)`. Your system is older?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a complete novice in this stuff, how do I check?

Comment: Can you also check edit 2 in the question? Could you use Zarko's code and output the image in your answer so I can temporarily use it in my document while we fix this problem? It's almost an identical table just with parameter values instead of description.

Comment: @Math (1) Open the `.log` file with a text editor. (2) Edit 2 added to my answer.

Comment: I dont have any `.log` files.. Also, sorry to bother you again, can you align the values in the "middle" like how its done with the parameters?

Comment: Could you have a look at this new question as you've answered this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643002/table-not-compiling

Answer (score 11):

With `tabularray` package you can simple combine rules from `booktabs` package and vertical lines. Additional advantage is that final form of table is achieved already after one compilation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} Q[c,$] X[l] |
                                    Q[c,$] X[l] @{}},
                       row{1} = {mode=text},
                     row{2-Y} = {belowsep+=2pt}
                     }  
    \toprule
Parameter & Description & Parameter & Description\\
    \midrule
\mu     & Influx rate of the popu\-la\-tion 
            & \epsilon  & Progression rate from $I_1$ to $I_2$  \\
\beta_1 & Transmission rate of the fast latent compartment 
            & p_1       & Progression rate from $I_2$ to $J$    \\
\beta_2 & Transmission rate of the symptomatic compartment 
            & p_2       & Progression rate from $J$ to $A$      \\
\beta_3 & Transmission rate of the AIDS compartment 
            & \xi_1     & Treatment rate from $J$ to $I_1$      \\
p       & Fraction of S infected by $I_2$ who enter $I_1$ 
            & \xi_2     & Treatment rate from $J$ to $I_2$      \\
q       & Fraction of S infected by $J$ who enter $I_1$ 
            & \nu       & Natural death rate                    \\
r       & Fraction of S infected by $A$ who enter $I_1$ 
            & \alpha    & Disease related death rate            \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case, that you like to have vertical lines at begin and end of table too, than the specification of your table should be:

```
\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {| Q[c,$] X[l] |
                                   Q[c,$] X[l] |},
                       row{1} = {mode=text},
                     row{2-Y} = {belowsep+=2pt}
                     }
```

Using it, the resulted table is:

[image]

**Addendum:**

As you asked me in comment, here is result of compilation of your code. In test I use the following preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
```

From it follows, that in test are used default font size (10pt) and default fonts (Computer Modern). Image shown here is cutout from screen by Snipping Tool (I use w10 OS), here is shown as png image with default setting of `imgur` settings.

[image]

A "fair" comparison is comparing resulted `pdf` files, where image are in vector format.

BTW, now I use `tabularray` package version 2022A (hopefully in few days with recent version 2022B available on CTAN from June 1st ;-). In your case results are the same from version 2021P further).

Comment: Running this code gives this error: `! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \UseTblrLibrary 
                                
l.28 \UseTblrLibrary
                    {booktabs}
? `

Comment: Which version `tabularray` you have? MWE in my answer is tested by 2021P and it works (no warnings, no errors). I check it again.

Comment: I don't know what version I have, how can I check?

Comment: hm, simplest way is try to upgrade your `tabularray` installation (or better, complete LaTeX installation). However, at begin of your document add `\listfiles` instruction which will at and of `.log` file collect all used packages with listed version. There you will see, which version use your system.

Comment: I still don't get a log file. I am using MikTex.

Comment: @Math, for sure is `log` file generated after each compilation. Since you have MiKTeX, open MiKTeX Console and click on button "Check for updates". Short after will be listed all packages which are not "up-to-date". Then click on button "Update now". I just check recent upgrades and see, that from December 2, is available version 2021Q. As expected, with it I can compile my MWE without errors.

Comment: I have installed the updates but it still doesn't work.. I have MikTex 2.9.6942 installed. I am using TexWorks as the compiler, there is no log file generated.

Comment: I don't know, what you doing.  Each compilation of `.tex` file generate `.log` and `.aux` file. They are in the sample place as is `.tex` file (except if you redirected it to some subfile). For sure the problem is not in my MWE but your MiKTeX installation.

Comment: shall I delete the current MikTex and re-download it?

Comment: @Math, if you like reinstall MiKTeX, you should first remove it from your PC. For this open MiKTeX console, stroke button "cleanup" and than "Remove MiKTeX".  When this proces is finished, start to install MiKTeX (as you like to have installed). When installation is finished, open MiKTeX Console and update it.

Comment: I came back to this, I tried installing the new version etc but still get errors. Temporarily I saved your photo and included that as a figure. I will ask again soon to fix it...

Comment: Please have a look at the edit, it will help me dearly..

Comment: @Math, i test your code in edited question. It gives the same result as is shown in answer (of course, since it is copy of mine in answer) . What is now a problem?

Comment: I managed to fix the compiling issue however why does your table look much better than mine when we compile identical codes? Please check edited photo in the question.

Comment: Is it to do with the font? I was using 12pt, what did you use?

Comment: @Math, what you compare? Resulted `pdf` files? They are the same quality (well your table now have different content that mine). If you compare images cut-up from screen and show here on site, than the result is dependent form your screen resolution and used tools for cutting of image.  I my screen has resolution 1920 x 1200, used tool is Snipping Tolls. See addendum to my answer.

Comment: I tried using the default 11pt, and we get identical tables.  Once again, thank you for answering my questions :))