# removing the figure caption to table caption?

Tags: tables, captions

For some reason the code provided by Zarko(below) isn't working on my computer:

[How to draw a vertical line in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624752/how-to-draw-a-vertical-line-in-a-table)

So temporarily I've decided to use his picture in his solution and included that as a png file:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{U4OxK.png}
\caption{Table 1: Description of parameters}
\label{top}
\end{figure}
```

This labels the figure as figure x: xxxxxxx. How do I remove it naming it figure x: bla bla bla to just table x: description of parameters, without changing my later figures order?

Edit: if someone knows the issue, I hope they can resolve it since it would be much better to use the actual code compared to the image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make figure a table:

[image: a]

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \begin{document}
        
        
        \begin{figure}[!htb]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{$p=0.9$, $q=0.8$, $r=0.7$, $\xi_1 =0.7$, $\xi_2 =0.8$  hence $\mathcal{R}_0 \approx 0.1599$.}
            \label{top}
        \end{figure} 
    
        \begin{table}[!htb]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{$p=0.9$, $q=0.8$, $r=0.7$, $\xi_1 =0.7$, $\xi_2 =0.8$  hence $\mathcal{R}_0 \approx 0.1599$.}
            \label{middle}
       \end{table} 
    
    
        \begin{figure}[!htb]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}
            \caption{$p=0.9$, $q=0.8$, $r=0.7$, $\xi_1 =0.7$, $\xi_2 =0.8$  hence $\mathcal{R}_0 \approx 0.1599$.}
            \label{bottom}
    \end{figure} 

\large

Top is Figure \ref{top}

Middle it Table \ref{middle}

Bottom is Figure \ref{bottom}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Could you also have a look at edit 2 in the question I linked, since you answered it before?

Comment: @Math I made an update to that question  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/624756/161015 on how to check the versions of the packages  and eventually update them.