# Compiling the following tables?

Tags: tables, typography

Can someone compile the following three tables and attach the outputs as a photo?

Table 1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}


\begin{document}
    \noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {| Q[c,$] X[l] |
                                       Q[c,$] X[l] |},
                           row{1} = {mode=text},
                         row{2-Y} = {belowsep+=2pt}
                         } 
    \toprule
Parameter & Description & Parameter & Description\\
    \midrule
b     & Influx rate of the popu\-la\-tion 
            & \sigma  & Progression rate from the asymptomatic compartment to the symptomatic compartment  \\
\mu & Natural death rate 
            & \gamma_A       & Non-treatment recovery rate of asymptomatic individuals \\
\beta_A & Transmission rate of the asymptomatic compartment 
            & \gamma_I       & Non-treatment recovery rate of symptomatic individuals      \\
\beta_I & Transmission rate of the symptomatic compartment 
            & \eta & Treatment rate of symptomatic individuals      \\
\nu       & Vaccination rate of newborns
            & \xi     & Immunity loss rate     \\
\rho       & Vaccination rate of susceptibles 
            & \alpha       & Disease induced death rate                    \\

    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Table 2:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}


\begin{document}
    \noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {| Q[c,$] X[l] |
                                       Q[c,$] X[l] |},
                           row{1} = {mode=text},
                         row{2-Y} = {belowsep+=2pt}
                         } 
        \toprule
    Parameter & Sensitivity index & Parameter & Sensitivity index\\
        \midrule
    b     & +1.000 
                & \sigma  & -0.447  \\
    \mu & -0.453 
                & \gamma_A       & -0.417    \\
    \beta_A & +0.891 
                & \gamma_I       & -0.013      \\
    \beta_I & +0.109 
                & \eta & -0.093      \\
    \nu       & -2.667 
                & \xi & +0.324      \\
    \rho       & -0.901 
                & \alpha       & -0.001                    \\
    
        \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Table 3:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{tabularray} 
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
    
    
    \begin{document}
        \noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {| Q[c,$] X[l] |
                                           Q[c,$] X[l] |},
                               row{1} = {mode=text},
                             row{2-Y} = {belowsep+=2pt}
                             } 
            \toprule
        Parameter & Sensitivity index & Parameter & Sensitivity index\\
            \midrule
        b     & +1.000 
                    & \sigma  & -0.215  \\
        \mu & -0.223 
                    & \gamma_A       & -0.052    \\
        \beta_A & +0.277 
                    & \gamma_I       & -0.594      \\
        \beta_I & +0.723 
                    & \eta     & -0.116     \\
        \nu       & -0.222 
                    & \xi     & +0.102      \\
        \rho       & -0.901 
                    & \alpha       & -0.001                    \\
        
            \bottomrule
        \end{tblr}
    \end{document}
```

***EDIT:***

This is the version I'm using:

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050)
entering extended mode

The error outputted in a fresh document:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `tabularray.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

EDIT 2:

After installing `tabularray` package and all the latest updates on MikTex console, my document that was compiling before is *not* compiling anymore with the following error:

```
Package tabularray Warning: Your LaTeX release is too old.
(tabularray)                Please update to 2020-10-01 first.

! Undefined control sequence.
\NewDashStyle code ..._tmpa_seq {4}}\tl_if_eq:NnT 
                                                  \l__tblr_a_tl {on}{\tl_if_...
l.1114 ...ashStyle {dashed} {on ~ 2pt ~ off ~ 2pt}
                                                  
?
```

***EDIT 3:***

Using Celdor's comments, I installed miktex from the link he sent, the tables compiled but they're not identical as I thought they'd be:

[image]

We see, the second is much "bulkier"? I want it like the one provided in Zarko's solution: [How to draw a vertical line in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624752/how-to-draw-a-vertical-line-in-a-table/624792?noredirect=1#comment1584855_624792) as it looks better in my opinion.

Comment: Please describe what problem you have with them.

Comment: @mickep I asked a similar question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624752/how-to-draw-a-vertical-line-in-a-table/624792?noredirect=1#comment1584855_624792. The table will not compile for me for some reason..

Comment: @Math show your log file, so it shows the version you have, and the error. As posted there is no question here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am using TeXworks, I don't see a log file. I just had a look at my other documents, none of them have a log filed saved..

Comment: The tables compile for me.

Comment: @egreg Strange it works for everyone but not me(!), I would of course not ask to compile a code if I could do it myself...

Comment: @Math In the directory with your .tex file you will find a .log file.  Look through the end of that to see what's wrong.  Texworks should also have an option to show you the console if something went wrong.

Comment: Can you updated your `TeX` distribution and then try?

Comment: @Teepeemm You find the log file in the same folder as the main document. And if they “don't compile” you should receive some error messages, don't you?

Comment: I have added the error I get in a fresh document in the question.

Comment: @Teepeemm There is no log file..

Comment: The error message says `tabularray`  is not installed. Did you try to install it with MiKTeX Package Manager?

Comment: texworks is just the editor you used to write the source, it is not related to the tex system you used to process the file.

Comment: @Bernard I have the packages installed with all the latest updates

Comment: I tried compiling again, now I have this error... edited in question

Comment: The error tells you about the missing package. If you have everything updated and still can't compile, with the same error, the package is still missing. The manager (of whatever distribution you are using) is not going to add anything else if it has not been installed in the first place, unless you explicitly instruct the manager to do so.

Comment: @Celdor I got another error after installing the package, see edit 2 in the question

Comment: Well, your distribution is too old for `tabularray` :) EDIT. Since you wrote, everything was up to date, I am afraid you will need to install TeX distribution, manually. Either TexLive or MikTeX will do.

Comment: @Celdor so what should I use?

Comment: I don't know how TeX is installed on your machine but you may need to uninstall the previous distribution, completely. Then, visit this link [Tex Live 2022](https://tug.org/texlive/), download an installer for your OS and run it. I would recommend to select everything (~7GB). If it's too much, you will have to add other packages on demand via a manager. The file should compile without errors, afterwards. As a side note, it doesn't matter where you compile it from: TexPad, TexStudio, or manually using command line!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136937/discussion-between-celdor-and-math).

Comment: Does the provided answer solve your problem? At least reply to it :)

Answer (score 1):

All tree tables compile in one page:

[image]

Your code with little changes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry} %<-- modified
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} Q[c,$] X[l] |
                                    Q[c,$] X[l] @{}},
                       row{1} = {mode=text},
                     row{2-Y} = {belowsep+=2pt}
                     }  
    \toprule
Parameter & Description & Parameter & Description\\
    \midrule
b     & Influx rate of the popu\-la\-tion 
            & \sigma  & Progression rate from the asymptomatic compartment to the symptomatic compartment  \\
\mu & Natural death rate 
            & \gamma_A       & Non-treatment recovery rate of asymptomatic individuals \\
\beta_A & Transmission rate of the asymptomatic compartment 
            & \gamma_I       & Non-treatment recovery rate of symptomatic individuals      \\
\beta_I & Transmission rate of the symptomatic compartment 
            & \eta & Treatment rate of symptomatic individuals      \\
\nu       & Vaccination rate of newborns
            & \xi     & Immunity loss rate     \\
\rho       & Vaccination rate of susceptibles 
            & \alpha       & Disease induced death rate                    \\

    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\vspace{.5cm} %<-- added

  \noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {| Q[c,$] X[l] |
            Q[c,$] X[l] |},
        row{1} = {mode=text},
        row{2-Y} = {belowsep+=2pt}
    } 
    \toprule
    Parameter & Sensitivity index & Parameter & Sensitivity index\\
    \midrule
    b     & +1.000 
    & \sigma  & -0.447  \\
    \mu & -0.453 
    & \gamma_A       & -0.417    \\
    \beta_A & +0.891 
    & \gamma_I       & -0.013      \\
    \beta_I & +0.109 
    & \eta & -0.093      \\
    \nu       & -2.667 
    & \xi & +0.324      \\
    \rho       & -0.901 
    & \alpha       & -0.001                    \\
    
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}

\vspace{.5cm}% <-- added

 \noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {| Q[c,$] X[l] |
            Q[c,$] X[l] |},
        row{1} = {mode=text},
        row{2-Y} = {belowsep+=2pt}
    } 
    \toprule
    Parameter & Sensitivity index & Parameter & Sensitivity index\\
    \midrule
    b     & +1.000 
    & \sigma  & -0.215  \\
    \mu & -0.223 
    & \gamma_A       & -0.052    \\
    \beta_A & +0.277 
    & \gamma_I       & -0.594      \\
    \beta_I & +0.723 
    & \eta     & -0.116     \\
    \nu       & -0.222 
    & \xi     & +0.102      \\
    \rho       & -0.901 
    & \alpha       & -0.001                    \\
    
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```