# How to use properly Excel2Latex?

Tags: excel2latex

This is just a simple testing of Excel2Latex:

[image: Table in Excel]

**Table in Excel**

[image: Table converted to Latex by Excel2Latex]

**Table converted to Latex by Excel2Latex**

### **Code in Latex for the table given by Excel2Latex:**

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Hoja1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|ccccc|c|}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & 4     & 5 \\
        \midrule
        0     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &       &  \\
        \midrule
        1     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &       &  \\
        \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-7}    2     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &       &  \\
        \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{4-7}    3     & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &       &  \\
        \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{5-7}    4     & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{}         &       &  \\
        \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{6-7}    5     & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{}                 &  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

I have installed all the necessary packages and the file compiles without errors, but the output is obviously unacceptable.

Is it possible to make any **adjustments to get the conversions from Excel to Latex correct**?

Comment: you have not shown usable code but `\midrule` suggests you are using `booktabs` whch explicitly documents that it is incompatible with vertical rules. Use `\hline`

Comment: You could try to see if the result is better when you unselect the `Booktabs package` option in the Excel2LaTeX window.

Comment: Uncheck  the "Booktabs package" from Options in Excel2Latex before saving.

Comment: However, if you want to keep using booktabs, you can also follow the advice in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/399741/ and add `\aboverulesep=0ex
\belowrulesep=0ex
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` before your table to remove the gaps.

Comment: Thank you, David. But, what is the equivalent for \cmidrule?

Comment: The bug with vertical lines is solved "Unchecking the "Booktabs package" from Options in Excel2Latex before saving", sugested by Simon Dispa and Marijin. Thank you very much to all!.

Comment: `\crule` is the non booktabs command