# Latex Table Missing Border Lines

Tags: tables, pdftex, document-classes

Once again when porting Latex Table code from one journal to springer format I am getting missing border lines( image attached). Latex code is as follows. Please suggest solution for missing border and auto line breaking to fit page width instead of manual I have done using `\\`

```
\usepackage{adjustbox} 
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\documentclass{sn-jnl}
\begin{document}

    \begin{table*}[!h]
        %\tiny
        \centering
        \small
        \caption{Result}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Users Set\\Size (USS)\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Range of Users \\ Individual \end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Index of scalar array \\ for mapping\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Transfer \\ Failure\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
            \multirow{6}{*}{6}                                                                        & \multirow{2}{*}{6}                    & 10                                                                                                       & 23                                                                                           \\ \cline{3-4} 
            &                                       & 4                                                                                                      & \textbf{18.3}                                                                                           \\ \cline{2-4} 
            & \multirow{2}{*}{7}                    & 0                                                                                                      & 13.3                                                                                          \\ \cline{3-4} 
            &                                       & 4                                                                                                       & \textbf{33.3}                                                                                           \\ \cline{2-4} 
            & \multirow{2}{*}{7}                    & 1                                                                                                       & 17                                                                                           \\ \cline{3-4} 
            &                                       & 2                                                                                                       & \textbf{66.6}                                                                                           \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
   \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should place `\documentclass{sn-jnl}` before loading any packages in your code. The document class is probably available from [here](https://www.springernature.com/de/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support). I'll look into it, but if I use the standard `article` class and add `\usepackage{multirow}`, I get a nicely typeset table.

Comment: @SimonDispa Since I provided an answer here, maybe we close the other question? Sorry, I did not see that this is in fact the same question asked before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `tabularray` and `siunitx` packages problems with vertical lines are eliminated and numbers in the last column are aligned at decimal points:

```
\documentclass{sn-jnl}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[ht]
    \caption{Result}
\sisetup{table-format=2.1,
         detect-weight, % <--
         }
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {X[c] X[1.2,c] X[1.8,c] X[c, si]},
             cell{even}{2} = {r=2}{},
             cell{odd[3]}{Z} = {font=\bfseries},
             row{1} = {guard}
             } 
Users Set Size (USS)
    &   Range of Users Individual
        &   Index of scalar array for mapping
            &   Transfer Failure        \\
\SetCell[r=6]{c}    6
    & 6 & 10& 23                        \\
    &   & 4 & 18.3                      \\
    & 7 & 0 & 13.3                      \\
    &   & 4 & 33.3                      \\
    & 7 & 1 & 17                        \\
    &   & 2 & 66.6                      \\
\end{tblr}
   \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the document class `sn-jnl` (2019/11/18 v0.1, line 1333) defines `\let\cline\cmidrule`. However, at that point, `\cmidrule` is still undefined, because the package `booktabs` hasn't been loaded at this point. This will result in an error since `\cline` is undefined. This should be actually be considered a bug in the code of the document class. You can work around this bug by loading the `booktabs` package using `\RequirePackage{booktabs}` before using `\documentclass` (`\usepackage` won't work before `\documentclass`).

However, putting this built-in bug aside, the authors of the document class obviously want you to use the `booktabs` package which [does not support vertical lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88929/47927). The use of the macros provided by this package, among which is also `\cmidrule`, insert some vertical spacing which breaks vertical rules. The `sn-jnl` class now sets `\cline` as alias to `\cmidrule`, which is why you get these broken borders.

There are two ways to get around this. The first way is to get along whith what the authors of this package probably intended and embrace features the provided by the `booktabs` package, that is, avoid the use of vertical lines and maybe even go without `\multirow`s:

```
\documentclass{sn-jnl}
\begin{document}

    \begin{table*}[!h]
        \centering
        \small
        \caption{Result}
        \begin{tabular}{ c c c c }
            \toprule
            \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} Users Set \\ Size (USS) \end{tabular} & 
            \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} Range of Users \\ Individual \end{tabular} & 
            \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} Index of scalar array \\ for mapping \end{tabular} &
            \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} Transfer \\ Failure \end{tabular} \\ 
            \midrule
            6  & 6  & 10  & 23            \\ \cline{3-4} 
               &    & 4   & \textbf{18.3} \\ \cline{2-4} 
               & 7  & 0   & 13.3          \\ \cline{3-4} 
               &    & 4   & \textbf{33.3} \\ \cline{2-4} 
               & 7  & 1   & 17            \\ \cline{3-4} 
               &    & 2   & \textbf{66.6} \\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Another, more hacky way would be to store the original `\cline` macro before loading the document class and later restore the definition of `\cline`:

```
\let\clineorig\cline
\documentclass{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table*}[!h]
        \centering
        \small
        \caption{Result}
        \let\cline\clineorig
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} Users Set \\ Size (USS) \end{tabular} & 
            \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} Range of Users \\ Individual \end{tabular} & 
            \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} Index of scalar array \\ for mapping \end{tabular} & 
            \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} Transfer \\ Failure \end{tabular} \\ 
            \hline
            \multirow{6}{*}{6} & \multirow{2}{*}{6} & 10  & 23            \\ \cline{3-4} 
                               &                    & 4   & \textbf{18.3} \\ \cline{2-4} 
                               & \multirow{2}{*}{7} & 0   & 13.3          \\ \cline{3-4} 
                               &                    & 4   & \textbf{33.3} \\ \cline{2-4} 
                               & \multirow{2}{*}{7} & 1   & 17            \\ \cline{3-4} 
                               &                    & 2   & \textbf{66.6} \\ 
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I personally would recommend the first solution.

---

As for the line breaking: It is totally fine to nest `tabulars`, but you don't need to place them inside `\multicolumn` macros. I simplified the code in this regard. Another way could be to apply the `p{}` column type which allows you to break lines, but you would need to tell LaTeX the width of the column (for example `p{1cm}` for a column width of 1cm).

Comment: Thanks all Specially @Zarko. In my other table I have 3 rows instead of two in the third column. To draw this I have modified cell{even}{2} = {r=2}{} to  cell{odd}{3} = {r=3}{} and also  \SetCell[r=6]{c} to \SetCell[r=9]{c} but I am getting errors

Comment: Thank you! I need a horizontal multi-column line as in the example of your first approach. However, it did not work. How about partially using your second approach by adding `\let\clineorig\cline` line before `documentclass` as in your example and use `\clineorig{3-4}` instead of `\cline{3-4}`? It works but I wonder if there is any drawbacks?

Comment: @burkay With `\let\clineorig\cline` you set the command `\clineorig` to behave exaxtly as `\cline` does at this point. So you kind of store the functionality of the `\cline` command before it is redefined. With the later `\let\cline\clineorig` the redefined `\cline` command is then restored to the original defintion. So, after this second line, both commands do exactly the same thing. Of course, you can just use `\clineorig` if you don't want to re-redefine `\cline` using `\let\cline\clineorig`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I started using \clineorig thanks to your answer. I felt like you implied the second approach might have some drawbacks. I was just wondering if that is the case even if we do not re-redefine. Anyway, thank you again.

Comment: @burkay I see. I don’t think that there are any drawbacks. It you don’t redefine, you keep the original definition without overriding the newer, so you can choose between both which is, as far as I can see, a good solution.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Awesome, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

For information, here what you obtain by using `{NiceTabular}` instead of `{tabular}`.

- I have loaded `nicematrix` with `\usepackage{nicematrix}` but `nicematrix` uses `pgf` and, in the class `sn-jnl`, `pgf` must be loaded *before* the `\documentclass` (with `\RequirePackage`).
- I have replaced `\begin{tabular}` and `end{tabular}` by `\begin{NiceTabular}` and `\end{NiceTabular}`.

```
\RequirePackage{pgf}
\documentclass{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Users Set\\Size (USS)\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Range of Users \\ Individual \end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Index of scalar array \\ for mapping\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Transfer \\ Failure\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
    \multirow{6}{*}{6}                                                                        & \multirow{2}{*}{6}                    & 10                                                                                                       & 23                                                                                           \\ \cline{3-4} 
    &                                       & 4                                                                                                      & \textbf{18.3}                                                                                           \\ \cline{2-4} 
    & \multirow{2}{*}{7}                    & 0                                                                                                      & 13.3                                                                                          \\ \cline{3-4} 
    &                                       & 4                                                                                                       & \textbf{33.3}                                                                                           \\ \cline{2-4} 
    & \multirow{2}{*}{7}                    & 1                                                                                                       & 17                                                                                           \\ \cline{3-4} 
    &                                       & 2                                                                                                       & \textbf{66.6}                                                                                           \\ \hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

The rules are not broken because, in the environments of `nicematrix`, `cline` is redefined (and that definition locally overwrite the redefinition of `\ncline` done by `sn-jnl`).

However, with `{NiceTabular}` the standard way to construct your table (with the tools of `nicematrix`) is as follows.

```
\RequirePackage{pgf}
\documentclass{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{table-format = 2.1,detect-weight}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccS}[hvlines]
\Block[l]{}{Users Set\\ Size (USS)}
& \Block[l]{}{Range of Users\\ Individual}
& \Block[l]{}{Index of scalar array\\ for mapping}
& \Block[l]{}{Transfer\\ Failure} \\
\Block{6-1}{6} & \Block{2-1}{6} & 10 & 23   \\
               &                & 4  & \bfseries 18.3 \\
               & \Block{2-1}{7} & 0  & 13.3 \\
               &                & 4  & \bfseries 33.3 \\
               & \Block{2-1}{7} & 1  & 17   \\
               &                & 2  & \bfseries 66.6 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]