# \cline cant function properly

Tags: tables, cline

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{multirow}

begin{table*}[b]
\centering
\caption{Summary of Electrical and Mechanical Fault Detection Method}
\label{Table:1}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{1cm}|p{1.75cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{4cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Fault Part} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Fault Type} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Fault Detection Method} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Signal Analysis Technique}                                             \\ 
\hline
\parbox[t]{1mm}{\multirow{18}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Induction Motor 
 (Electrical Based Fault)}}}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{Broken Rotor Bar}} & Model Based Approach - DAE-SVM & Fast Fourier Transform
\\ \cline{3-4} 
                             &                                               & 
                             MCSA & Wavelet Transform \newline{Stockwell Transform} \newline{Hilbert Transform} \newline{Short time Fourier Transform}  \\ \cline{3-4} 
                             &                                               &
                             Improved Bare-Bones Particle Swarm Optimization  & Multiple Signal Classification \& Discrete Fourier Transform \\ \cline{3-4}
                              &                                               & Computing The Homogeneity and Kurtosis & Discrete Fourier Transform  \\ \cline{2-4} 
                              
                             & \multirow{4}{*}{Bearing}                       & 
                             MCSA & Wavelet Transform \newline{Stock well Transform} \newline {Hilbert Huang Transform} \\ \cline{3-4} 
                             &                                               & Vibration Measurements & Fast Fourier Transform \\  \cline{3-4}
                             &                                               & 
                             High Frequency Demodulation & Local Low Rank Matrix Approximation \newline{Fast Fourier Transform} \\ \cline{2-4} 
                           
                             
                              & \multirow{4}{*}{Stator Winding}                    &Model Based Approach-Tacholess Order Tracking
                              & Fast Fourier Transform \\ \cline{3-4} 
                             &                                               & 
                             Finite Element Analysis  & Stockwell Transform \\  \cline{3-4}
                             &                                               & Support Vector Machine (SVM) &  Fast Fourier Transform \\ \cline{1-4}

\parbox[t]{1mm}{\multirow{18}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ESP (Mechanical Based Fault)}}}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{Breakage (Shaft Failure)}} & Model Based Approach - DAE-SVM & Fourier Transform \\ \cline{3-4}
                             &                                               & 
                             MCSA & Wavelet Transform \newline{Stock well Transform} \newline {Hilbert Huang Transform}  \\ \cline{3-4} 
                             &                                               &
                             Torsional Dynamic Stress Analysis  &  N/A \\ \cline{3-4}
                              &                                               & Support Vector Machine & Fast Fourier Transform\\ \cline{2-4} 
                              
                             & \multirow{3}{*}{Impeller}                       & 
                             MCSA & Wavelet Transform \newline{Stock well Transform \&} \newline {Hilbert Huang Transform\&}\newline {Modulation Signal Bispectrum} \\ \cline{3-4} 
                             &                                               & Adaptive Chirp Mode Decomposition (ADMD)  & Instantaneous Frequency analysis \newline {Zero-Crossing Time (ZCT) Technique}
  \\  \cline{3-4}
                             &                                               & 
                             High Frequency Demodulation & Fast Fourier Transform  \\ \cline{2-4} 
                           
                             
                              & \multirow{4}{*}{Leakage}                    
                              &Downhole Sensor& N/A \\ \cline{3-4} 
                             &                                               & 
                             Principal Component Analysis & Artificial Neural Network  \\  \cline{3-4}
                             &                                               & Mahalonobis Distance& N/A \\ \cline{3-4}
                            
                             \hline
                             

\end{tabular}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image: this is what i got]

Comment: Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: what is your question?  `\cline`will not give an error if used correctly, but if you do not show how you used it or what error you got, we can not help

Comment: im sorry, im just edited the question. really hope you can help me

Comment: @TUANSHARIFAHNURFATIEHATUAN Your code does not compile. There is no `\begin{document}`

Comment: The `sn-jnl` class sets `\let\cline\cmidrule` and does a lot of other questionable things. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/678195/47927

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `sn-jnl` class is not included in a standard TeX distribution. Therefore please add a link to it and please also make sure that the code example you provide is compilable (except for the error regarding `\cline`). It seems that the `sn-jnl` requires you to load a selection of packages of which one is the `booktabs` package. As I discussed in my answer linked in my comment above, I assume that this document class requires you to adhere to the styling suggestions and macros provided by the `booktabs` package (which does not allow for vertical rules).