# Latex '\cline' command throwing error

Tags: templates, multirow, cline, springer

I am writing a manuscript for Springer Nature. My Latex code is as follows.

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[ruled,nofillcomment]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=30mm,bmargin=30mm,lmargin=30mm,rmargin=20mm}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!t]
\centering
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Col 1 & Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4 & Col 5 \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{R-1} & A1 & B1 & C1 & D1 \\ \cline{2-5}
& E1 & F1 & G1 &  H1 \\ \cline{1-5}
\multirow{2}{*}{R-2} & A2 & B2 & C2 & D2 \\ \cline{2-5}
& E2 & F2 & G2 & H2 \\ \cline{1-5}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\scriptsize{Sample Table Data}}
\label{Table1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

While running, this code is showing the following error.

**! Undefined control sequence.
 \cline

l.44 ...w{2}{*}{R-1} & A1 & B1 & C1 & D1 \ \cline
{2-5}**

However, when I am using a different *documentclass*, the code is running fine. How can I make this table work in Springer Nature template?

[image: The expected output is]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, in nothing error in your code, but you are using customized class file `sn-jnl`, problem might be with that

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/678196/36296

Comment: Yes this is working!! Thank you @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: I get `! LaTeX Error: Command \algorithm already defined.` and `! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (|): `c' used.`  (the latter is because of `program.sty`)

Comment: don't use `epsfig` package for documents written after 1993

Comment: You also load `graphicx` and `graphics`, but the former already loads the latter. Then, you load `amssymb` and `amsthm` twice, and the `tabu` package is [broken](https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu) and should probably be replaced by a newer package such as `tabularray`.