# Why I get undefined control sequence with cline?

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make that table:

```
\documentclass[default]{sn-jnl}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{adjustbox}%

\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 
\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\title[Some title]{Some title}

\abstract{Some abstract}

\maketitle

\section{INTRODUCTION}
.....

\begin{table*}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Statistical tests.\label{tab:II}}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=1.0\textwidth,center}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{Algorithm} & \multirow{5}{*}{No. of streams} \\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{$\qquad \qquad  \qquad  \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad$ Inter-stream correlation} \\[6pt]
\cline{3-6}
 &   & \multirow{2}{*}{NIST} & \multirow{2}{*}{Dieharder} & \multirow{2}{*}{TestU01} & \multirow{2}{*}{PractRand (bytes)} \\[11pt]
\hline \\
\textbf{A}  & $2^{127}$   & $>$ min. pass rate    &passed  & passed    & $>2^{43}$, $>2^{43}$  \\[7pt]
\textbf{B} & $2^{63}$  & $>$ min. pass rate    &passed   & passed    & $>2^{43}$, $>2^{43}$  \\[7pt]
\textbf{C}  & $2^{63}$ & $>$ min. pass rate    &passed   & passed    & $>2^{43}$, $>2^{43}$ \\[7pt]
CG32    & $2^{31}$  & not applied    &not applied  & not applied    & $> 2^{43}$, $< 2^{34}$ \\[7pt]
CG64-32   & $2^{31}$  & not applied    &not applied  & not applied    & $> 2^{43}$, $< 2^{35}$  \\[7pt]
CG16    & $2^{15}$ & not applied    &not applied  & not applied    &$< 2^{24}$, $< 2^{17}$  \\[7pt]
CG32-16  & $2^{15}$  & not applied    &not applied  & not applied  & $< 2^{20}$, $< 2^{18}$ \\[7pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table*}%
\raggedbottom


\bibliography{cg-bibliography}

\end{document}
```

But I can't use cline, beacuse I get undefined control sequence. How to make that cline?

The full log:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.472 \cline
{3-6}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: `sn-jnl` is not a standard class, so I can't compile your example as it is.  If I change the class to `article`, then I don't get an error.  Can you trim this down to a minimal example that shows the error you're getting?

Comment: @Teepeemm What could be minimal example other than one I showed?

Comment: I get no error, using `sn-jnl`, show the full log. Your example is far from minimal do you need `\usepackage{manyfoot}%` to show the error. A minimal example would have much smaller log and be much easier to debug

Comment: Ok, I added more error informations.

Comment: Did you see [Q678195](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/678195/47927)? It might be related.

Comment: @JasperHabicht It was my first thought too but `booktabs` is loaded here.

Comment: Work through https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497.  Delete the multirow and multicolumn commands.  Delete the adjustbox environment (and never use it again).  Do you still have the error?  Delete the theoremstyles and newtheorems.  Do you still have the error?  Delete every package (except for booktabs).  Do you still have the error?

Comment: @JasperHabicht Oooh, now I see. The class does `\let\cline\cmirdule` but of course at that point `\cmidrule` is undefined. One should load `booktabs` before the document class. A very badly written class.

Comment: @Teepeemm yes, I still have that error.

Comment: I will just delete that clines. By the way do you have any idea what other type of document compatible with \documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart} I could use to send it to International Journal of Information Technology? Beacuse all my questions so far are beacuse I have perfectly fine paper in ACM style and I can't convert it to that Springer requirements. Other types of document also usually are destroying my paper.

Comment: @campa Yes, I edited my answer to the other question. The solution is actually to place `\RequirePackage{booktabs}` *before* `\documentclass`.

Comment: The sn-jnl class exists in two varieties bearing the same version information. One loads several useless packages, the one which you seem to be using got rid of almost all packages, even of those that are essential for it to work. You need to load yourself at least `manyfoot` and `booktabs`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Upps, I had already written my answer before I read you reply...

Comment: @Teepeemm If I will delete adjustbox my tables won't fit on the page. So what should I do in that case?

Comment: You can refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/107497.  For this table, I think the NIST, Dieharder, and TestU01 columns don't need to be in the table and can be explained elsewhere.  Actually, I'm betting that you've already explained them elsewhere, because what you've shown is too terse to really understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The class is written quite horribly. If you don't *have* to use it, then use another one.

Anyway, the problem *here* is that it defines `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` similar to those of `booktabs` but... no idea what is supposed to happen after that. After these definitions you find

```
\let\cline\cmidrule
```

but the trouble is that at this point `\cmidrule` is not defined, and using it in the document will result in the error.

There are some workarounds but none will result in whatever the class is probably supposed to do.

1. You can load `\RequirePackage{booktabs}` before `\documentclass`. In this way you have a working `\cline` (which is the same as `\cmidrule`) but the class will overwrite the definition of `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`.
2. You can add `\usepackage{booktabs}\let\cline\cmidrule` in the preamble. Everything should then work, but the class' own definitions will be overwritten.
3. You can copy the original definition of `\cline` and restore it afterwards `\let\LaTeXcline\cline\documentclass{sn-jnl}\let\cline\LaTeXcline`. Then you'll have `\cline` and`\cidrule` doing different things.

I don't know which one's worse `;-)`

Comment: Do you know what type of document compatible with \documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart} I could use to send it to International Journal of Information Technology? They suggest that one I'm using now, but maybe they could accept also other type.

Comment: I used first soultion and it works.