# \cmidrule instead of \cline error

Tags: tables, rules

I am using sn-jnl class for journal submission. unfortunately it does not recognize \cline in muticolum table. Also tried \Requirespackage{bookstab} but still errors. Therfore used \cmidrule but the lines are broken (discontinuos). Following code i tried and result is attached. I need connected lines. Thanks[image]

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{Parameters Impact}
    \label{table:impact}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}D -X\end{tabular}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Y- Z \end{tabular}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Numbers \end{tabular}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} TT (/\%)\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
        \multirow{6}{*}{3} & \multirow{2}{*}{3} & 1 & 22.1 \\ 
        \cmidrule{3-4} 
        &                    & 3 & 22 \\ 
        \cmidrule{2-4} %\cline{2-4} 
        & \multirow{2}{*}{5} & 2 & 16 \\ 
        \cmidrule{3-4} 
        &                    & 5 & 40 \\ 
        \cmidrule{2-4} 
        & \multirow{2}{*}{6} & 7 & 30 \\ 
        \cmidrule{3-4} 
        &                    & 8 & 45 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please run through this checklist and improve the code you posted: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137 . Thank you

Comment: The problem is known. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/678196/47927

Comment: @JasperHabicht It's not a problem, it's a feature :D

Comment: @CarLaTeX Well, I am usure that setting `\let\cline\cmidrule` as it is done by the `sn-jnl` class can really be said to be a feature since it reather leads to confusion than to improved typesetting ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht I meant the discontinuos vertical rules

Comment: @CarLaTeX Yes, this is a feature, for sure! =) If they want to use vertical rules, the OP should rather use `\cline`, but as the document class does `\let\cline\cmidrule`, the output will still be the same. So, I would recommend not using vertical rules at all and stick to the style suggested by the `booktabs` package.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Exactly!